# Compatible Query for inserting null values in datafields

Tags: oracle

oracle and mysql  supports (date '2013-07-01').BUt i want to store Empty date in both database.This format support (date '0000-00-00')and NULL in mysql.This format support in 
(date '2013-07-01') only in oracle it doesn't allow NULL or (date '0000-00-00').how to rewrite this query into compatible ????

Comment: you can't insert a null in mysql?  Maybe I misunderstand the question tho

Comment: Are your sure? please check this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70c97/1), in that example I insert a **null** value into **date** field. I do not understand your problem, please post your query. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't [ask the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17723040/266304). You should have edited the original question to clarify what you needed. Since this one now has an answer, maybe you should delete the other one?

Answer (score 0):

For identical MySQL-Oracle syntax for empty dates, try `CAST(NULL AS DATE)`. It works in Oracle, and I'm pretty sure it works in MySQL but I can't verify this because I don't have MySQL available this morning and SQLFiddle is having one of its bad "timeout" days.

The [MySQL `CAST` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) implies that this syntax would be OK.

Comment: thanks for giving corret solution